# Why doesn't my WWW::Mechanize submit a PayPal form work?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp

Nothing I've tried can get my code to submit correctly. Can anyone else figure this out?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;


my $user = 'cowsaremyfriends@gmail.com';
my $pass  = 'hackswipe';
# Test account; don't worry


my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$browser->get("https://www.paypal.com/");
$browser->form_with_fields("login_email", "login_password");
$browser->field("login_email", $user);
$browser->field("login_password", $pass);
$browser->submit_form();
$browser->get("https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-add-direct-access");
##### Help here ---> Trying to submit form with default option selected #####
my $html = $browser->content;

print $html;
```

Comment: Your code work for me. What problem you have?

Comment: By any chance, has the IP been blacklisted/banned?

Comment: What is happening, vs. what you expect to happen? You do not clearly state the actual problem you are having.

Comment: The problem is that once I get to the page before the comment, I'm lost as to how to make that form submit. Various methods I've attempted in place of that comment have failed.

The code already there works, yes, but I'm having trouble writing more working code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me, but when it comes to debugging web scrapers, etc, you should watch the HTTP transaction. That's really easy to add since [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) is an [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl) subclass:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();

# See LWP::Debug
$browser->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$browser->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });
```

Now you can see what you send and what PayPal sends back.

Often you can also use various HTTP sniffing tools, but those only work for things that you  send in plaintext, so you're out of luck here.

In this case, however, PayPal is on to you. They know you are using a script. Part of the output I get is:

```
<h2>Request API Credentials</h2>
</div>
<div id="messageBox"></div>
<div id="main"><div class="layout1"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8dc18bca4c6f47e633b393e284a5f8a8f8" class="">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_profile-api-add-direct-access"><input type="hidden" name="api_flow_origin" value=""><input type="hidden" name="show_switch" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="auth_type" value="ssl"><input type="hidden" name="api_username" value=""><input type="hidden" name="program_name" value=""><input type="hidden" name="program_id" value=""><input type="hidden" name="partner_name" value=""><input type="hidden" name="partner_id" value=""><input type="hidden" name="partner_code" value=""><p>API credentials consist of three elements:</p>
<ul>
<li>An API username</li>
<li>An API password</li>
<li>Either an API signature or an API SSL client-side certificate</li>
</ul>
<p>If you’re using a shopping cart or solution provider, ask whether you need an API signature or a certificate.</p>
```

If you want to interact with PayPal through a program, you need to [sign up for developer access](https://developer.paypal.com/).

Comment: The problem is that once I get to the page before the comment, I'm lost as to how to make that form submit. Various methods I've attempted in place of that comment have failed.

The code already there works, but I'm having trouble writing more working code.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you have to explain what you want to do. Edit your original question to tell us what you are trying to do, what you tried, and how it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up getting around this a completely different way.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what the problem is, exactly.  Have you read the FAQ?

```
perldoc WWW::Mechanize::FAQ
```

It gives suggestions on how to debug problems with Mech.  The first thing I'd have to ask is if the form is using JavaScript.  I'd bet a nickel that PayPal's pages are doing that.

Comment: The problem is that once I get to the page before the comment, I'm lost as to how to make that form submit. Various methods I've attempted in place of that comment have failed.

Thanks.